# Значение слова  "флэшмоб"

Tags: семантика

Последнее время часто попадается на глаза слово **флэшмоб**. Из контекста как-то поняла. Оказалось, неверно. В словарях нет, в интернет-источниках объяснения противоположные:

1. Толпа, которая собралась мгновенно, неожиданно
2. Заранее спланированная массовая акция.

Какое же значение имеет это слово? Пожалуйста, приведите примеры корректного его употребления.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> В словарях нет, в интернет-источниках объяснения противоположные: 1. Толпа, которая собралась мгновенно, неожиданно 2. Заранее спланированная массовая акция.

Все правильно. ***Неожиданная для окружающих, но заранее спланированная массовая акция***. Остаётся только добавить, что для настоящего флешмоба акция должна быть эпатажной, но безобидной (в плане закона в частности).

Comment: В прошлом году попала случайно на такую акцию, просто мимо шла. Непонятно откуда появились люди (много), которые вдруг стали пускать мыльные пузыри. Через час все разошлись. Было весело и неожиданно. Участники рассказывали, что договаривались об акции в сети.

Answer (score 4):

Это не противоположные значения, в вполне взаимодополняющие. Флэшмоб - это заранее спланированная массовая акция, когда в одном условленном месте собирается неожиданно большая толпа. Причины, поведение, цель может быть какой угодно. Хотя бы все собрались, помолчали (потанцевали, помахали руками, постояли на голове...) и разошлись :-)) Причем разошлись так же неожиданно, как и собрались.

Например: " На сайтах флэшмоберов можно прочитать о том, что житель Нью-Йорка Билл, используя sms и e-mail, собрал около полутора сот незнакомых друг с другом человек, которые 17 июня 2003 года одновременно вошли в мебельный отдел магазина "Macy's" и попросили "любовный ковер" для "пригородной коммуны" ценой в $10 000. Телевидение в свое время достаточно подробно осветило эту акцию и именно ее принято считать первым флэшмобом."

Больше почитать можно здесь: [Что такое флэшмоб? | Культура | ШколаЖизни.ру](http://shkolazhizni.ru/archive/0/n-1194/)

Comment: Почему неожиданно, если заранее известно? НЕ понимаю? У нас объявление: ...на городской площади в честь Дня города состоится грандиозный флэшмоб. Так правильно?

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Оттуда: "В конечном итоге, любая уличная акция в скором времени будет называться флэшмобом лишь потому, что эта форма активности не присутствует в законодательстве." Я тоже так подумала, правда безотносительно к законодательству. А просто потому, что новое модное словечко.

Comment: Нет это не флэшмоб. Основные принципы флэшмоба: 1)спонтанность; 2)отсутствие централиз.руководства; 3)отсутствие каких-либо полит., финанс. или рекламных целей; 4)деперсонификация;участники флэшмоба (в идеале это абсолютно незнакомые люди) во время акции не должны никак показывать, что их что-то связывает; 5)отказ от освещения флэшмоба в СМИ.

Comment: Судя по акциям, которые наши доморощенные специалисты по организации массовых акций позиционируют как флэшмоб,создается впечатление,что образцом флэшмоба для них является советский субботник. В итоге,любая уличная акция скоро будет называться флэшмобом лишь потому,что этой формы активности нет в законодательстве.

Comment: Нет. Повторюсь, для флешмоба необходима эпатажность и отсутствие существенных нарушений общественного порядка и законодательства в целом.  
Ни выход на улицы с плакатами "Свободу Ходору", ни акция "Пусси райот" таковыми не являются.

Comment: А как связана с этим словом флэшка?

Comment: Никак. Только общей английской основой flash со значением быстро промелькнуть, осенить (с производным - мгновенный). Flash mob - "мгновенно пораженная толпа"; flash drive - устройство мгновенной памяти и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо...

Answer (score 0):

*Флешмо́б или флэшмоб — это заранее спланированная массовая акция, в которой большая группа людей появляется в общественном месте, выполняет заранее оговоренные действия (сценарий) и затем расходится. Флешмоб является разновидностью смартмоба. Сбор участников флешмоба осуществляется посредством связи (в основном это Интернет).
Основные принципы флешмоба.
Спонтанность в широком смысле.
Отсутствие централизованного руководства, избранного командира.
Отсутствие каких-либо финансовых или рекламных целей.
Деперсонификация; участники флешмоба (в идеале это абсолютно незнакомые люди) во время акции не должны никак показывать, что их что-то связывает.
Отказ от освещения флешмоба в СМИ.
Противоположным флешмобу по идее и задачам проведения является профлеш.
Флешмоб рассчитан на случайных зрителей, вызывая смешанные чувства непонимания, интереса и даже участия*

Comment: Слово в слово комментарий Оlsa.

Comment: >Слово в слово комментарий Оlsa.  
  
А буквы - так вообще... Ну прямо как Кирилла с Мефодием.

Answer (score -1):

Флеш - Моб

Флеш - Вспышка, Возможно ярких впечатлений для окружающих, или же для самих участников.

Моб - из компьютерных игр, программно управляемые персонажи. Автор идеи организует персонажей выполнить заданную программу.

ФлешМоб - особая форма организации случайных участников в мероприятии для выражения некоей авторской идеи, зачастую просто массово по-озорничать, с целью доставить себе и окружающим массу ярких впечатлений. Как особая форма проведения досуга.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?